# TouchSwipe Jquery Plugin, How to add left and right swipe listener and enable scrolling vertically?

Tags: android, jquery, cordova

I use the below code for listening left and right swipe. But I cannot scroll vertically by swiping. Please help

```
$(function() {

  $("#div_with_drawer").swipe( {
    //Generic swipe handler for all directions
       swipe:function(event, direction, distance, duration, fingerCount, fingerData) {
            if(direction=='right')
                $('.drawer').drawer('close');
            else if(direction=='left')
                $('.drawer').drawer('open');
        }
    });
```

});

Comment: I changed the code like this and it worked.

Comment: $(function() {
 $("#div_with_drawer").swipe( { swipeLeft:swipe1, allowPageScroll:"horizontal"} );
 function swipe1(event, direction, distance, duration, fingerCount) {
  $('.drawer').drawer('open');
 }

 $("#div_with_drawer").swipe( { swipeDown:swipe2, allowPageScroll:"vertical"} );
 $("#div_with_drawer").swipe( { swipeUp:swipe2, allowPageScroll:"vertical"} );
 function swipe2(event, direction, distance, duration, fingerCount) {
  // $('.drawer').drawer('open');
 }
});